# C++ string construct performance

Tags: c++, string, performance

I was wondering if below code has any difference between #1, #2 and #3 when passing a string to a function (eg. insert into a vector). Especially when dealing with millions of strings in the code.

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string s("foo");
int i = 1;
v.push_back( s + "bar" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) );  // #1
v.push_back( std::string(s + "bar" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i)) );  // #2
std::string s2 = s + "bar" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
v.push_back(s2);  // #3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a decent optimizer there *should* be no difference between #1 and #2, but #1 gives you the biggest chance that the compiler actually does temporary elimination.

However, #3 contains a named temporary, so it probably needs a great optimizer to detect that it's just that - a temporary.

Comment: push_back takes T as const&.  The compiler will be binding the temporary created by the expression or the one passed in as a variable.  It won't make a bit of difference.

Comment: @CrazyEddie : In C++11 there's a big difference – #1 and #2 are rvalues and will be moved into the `vector` automatically, #3 would need to be moved explicitly.

Comment: What if I need to loop through these code million times, is there an efficient way to reuse the memory space for the temporary string? Just like the way C# does with StringBuilder class. It only creates once, and reuses the memory over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  They should be equivalent.

One way you could get performance gain though is by pre-allocating your string:

```
std::string s;
s.reserve(10); // or so...
s.append("foobar").append(lexical_cast<std::string>(i));
```

You probably would not gain enough performance here to make it worth the hassle though.